# Transparent Caching for HTTP

Tags: linux, cache

I don't have a clue where to start on caching, and I'm already lost in googling it.

I just want to run a server on an Ubuntu machine that will take a list of internet URLs, download a local copy of every page under that URL, and then configure my system so that when any process requests that URL (a browser, wget, apt-get, etc), it will be accessing the local copy without knowing it.

And a second-priority requirement: allow processes on the local system to call *by URL* either the locally-cached version or the live-internet version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
It is a Web-cache Proxy

Answer (score 1):

The popular Squid Proxy can be setup as a transparent proxy with help from iptables.

Googling "squid transparent proxy" had this as the top link:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html